# I am getting decimal values as Classes in R programming but I should be getting natural numbers

Tags: r

The column 'A' has values such as 0,1,2. Depending upon other columns of data, I should be predicting the value of 'A' I am using the rpart() function but I am getting decimal values (0.3961, 0.688, 0.012 etc when I plot the tree) in the output instead of natural numbers(0,1,2)

```
formulaA = A ~ car_value + car_age + age_oldest + age_youngest + duration_previous + group_size + homeowner + risk_factor + married_couple
fit = rpart(formulaA, method = "class", data = trainNONA0)
plot(fit) # plotting the tree so that I can see the classification and the nodes.
text(fit) # labeling the tree
```

The data frame has following columns: 
    customer_ID group_size  homeowner   car_age         car_value                risk_factor    age_oldest  age_youngest    married_couple  C_previous      duration_previous   A   B   C   D

I should use the other attributes for predicting A, B, C and D. I am trying to predict them individually(Because we cannot predict more than one attribute using decision trees). The output should be a natural number. A can have 0,1,2 ; B- 0,1 ; C-1,2,3,4 and D-1,2,3. The below is the sample values of A,B,C,D.
    {1  0   2   2;
    1   0   2   2;
    1   0   2   2;
    0   0   3   2;
    0   0   3   2;
    0   0   3   2;
    0   0   2   3;
    1   1   3   2;
    1   1   3   2;
    1   1   3   3;
    2   1   1   1;
    1   1   1   1;
    1   1   1   1;}

So, the end node should be 0 or 1 or 2 but the plot gives end nodes as (0.3961, 0.688, 0.012 etc)

Comment: Please edit your question to include example data that shows the problem.  It is probably not necessary to have so many columns.

Comment: Sorry about that, I have edited the question and put enough information now.

Comment: If you are still having this problem, please paste the output of `dput(trainNONA0[1:10, ]) at the end of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try 
    predict(fit, type="class")
to get the predicted class rather than the vector of class probabilities.

Here is an example:

```
> data(cars)
> m<-rpart(speed~dist, data=cars)
> predict(m, type="class")
Error in predict.rpart(m, type = "class") : 
Invalid prediction for "rpart" object
> # Doesn't work
> m<-rpart(speed~dist, data=cars, method="class")
> predict(m, type="class")
 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
12 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 12 12 12 12 12 12 12 13 13 13 12 13 20 24 12 12 20 ...
```

Comment: Hi, tnq for the reply but I got the following error when i tried it:

Error in predict.rpart(fit, type = "class") : 
  Invalid prediction for "rpart" object

Comment: Are you quite sure you fit the model "fit" with the `method = "class"` option? I will post an example above.

Comment: The above example helped :)
I have used it as: result <-predict(fit,type="class",data=trainNONA0)
summary(result) 
.. I am using the same training set for prediction too, just to see if its predicting the values  correctly. But the prediction is turning out to be wrong.
 A- should contain values 0,1,2 but its predicting the values 0,1 only and value 2 was not among the predictions.

Comment: How can you tell that they are wrong? Ordinarily the predictions would not exactly match the value of A.

Comment: The original data has some values as '2' in the column 'A' and when I try to get the summary of result, summary(result)
    0     1     2 
 7094 55161     0  it shows That there were 0 instances of '2' for attribute 'A'